# Redis 'Client closed connection' error

Tags: node.js, redis

I just launched a site running on redis.

After a few hours, redis stops working and I have to restart the server to get it working again.

This is what the log shows:

```
[3336] 18 Oct 17:59:18 - DB 0: 1339 keys (1337 volatile) in 512 slots HT.
[3336] 18 Oct 17:59:18 - 5 clients connected (0 slaves), 1903440 bytes in use
[3336] 18 Oct 17:59:21 - Client closed connection
[3336] 18 Oct 17:59:23 - DB 0: 1341 keys (1339 volatile) in 512 slots HT.
[3336] 18 Oct 17:59:23 - 4 clients connected (0 slaves), 1896008 bytes in use
```

It stopped working exactly when the 'Client closed connection' showed up in the log.

Any idea why that might be happening?

**Update: It shut down again. This time I checked the memory and it was beyond 3.5 GB. Does that have anything to do with it?**

Comment: `Client closed connection` <- your client is crashing, not redis.

Comment: does redis-server exits ? if not do you notice high cpu usage or really high memory usage (if yes report what free -m or alike tools tell you)

Comment: Is Redis still responding to pings sent via redis-cli when you think it is no longer working for you?

Comment: last, what do you solve? i meet same problem. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131736/redis-it-seems-like-server-has-closed-the-connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131736/redis-it-seems-like-server-has-closed-the-connection)