# redis It seems like server has closed the connection

Tags: java, redis, jedis

i want to use redis sub/pub, but when i subscribe one channel, 2 minutes after,console output Exception: 
    It seems like server has closed the connection.

redis version：redis-3.0.3

jedis version：2.3.0

os：OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Subscribe.class

```
    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(10);
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWait(4000);
    jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, "127.0.0.1", 6379);

    final Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
    System.out.println(jedis.configGet("timeout"));
    System.out.println(jedis.configGet("tcp-keepalive"));
    final JedisPubSub jedisPubSub = new JedisPubSub() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
            System.out.println("onMessage");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPMessage(String pattern, String channel, String message) {
            System.out.println("onPMessage");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
            System.out.println("onSubscribe");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnsubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
            System.out.println("onUnsubscribe");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPUnsubscribe(String pattern, int subscribedChannels) {
            System.out.println("onPUnsubscribe");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPSubscribe(String pattern, int subscribedChannels) {
            System.out.println("onPSubscribe");
        }
    };
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    jedis.subscribe(jedisPubSub, "/atm/test");
```

Publish.class

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("127.0.0.1", 6379);
jedis.publish("/atm/test", "lqiaing---hello");
```

then 2 minutes after console output:

```
[timeout, 0]
[tcp-keepalive, 0]
2015-12-03 19:01:55
onSubscribe
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: 
It seems like server has closed the connection.
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readLine(RedisInputStream.java:91)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processMultiBulkReply(Protocol.java:110)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:63)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:122)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:196)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub.process(JedisPubSub.java:88)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub.proceed(JedisPubSub.java:83)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.subscribe(Jedis.java:1974)
at Subscribe.main(Subscribe.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

anyone can help me? very thanks！

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OSX user but it might be the OS that's configured to kill TCP connections that exceed the 120 seconds. Have you tried setting the tcp-keepalive option in some value (like 30 secs) to check if the connection still dies?.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i set tcp-keepalive=10 and timeout=10, and i also tested on windows and ubuntu system.   but still output this Exception.